# Task manager does not want to perform tasks when user is not logged in

Tags: python, batch-file, taskmanager

So I have a python script that performs via .bat file, and its execution is setup under Windows Task Manager. The script is supposed to login to our internal website with specific credentials, download the data, connect to API and verify the data. Once data are verified, the script returns a pdf and excel file to the specified folder in our internal portal.

We use the following libraries:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import io
import csv
import re
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import base64
from weasyprint import HTML, CSS
import datetime
from jinja2 import Template
import smtplib, ssl
import chardet
```

When I set the task to perform when the user is logged on, there is no problem - task executes as defined. However, when I change the setting to perform if the user is not logged in, the task does not perform. In the history there are no errors, you can just see that the task is setup, but there are no execution logs.

The performance of the script is setup for admin (user with highest authorization), and both .bat and .py files run under the local system.

Also we have tried running it as a user, but it didn't change anything.

I have read all the answers on similar topics, and there is no clear solution to this issue (apart from the things that we have already discussed in this topic). Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: When no user is logged on the path is not what you would expect. Starting folder is \windows\system32, there are no mapped drives (no z: = \\someServer\someFolder), task may run under LocalSystem or a defined user account both (maybe) without enough privileges to access resources. So, as a starting point, if you access resources in another computer/drive, enter full uncpath or map the resource in your bat file (ie using pushd), fully qualify paths to any file\location, run task under a user account with enough privileges to access resources.

Comment: ALso, bear in mind, (as you are running a python scrpt) that python may expect a well defined environment (path, user credentials, drives, etc) are they set at the moment the task runs?

Comment: Hi @elzooilogico, I have already read your answer someplace else, and as said above, everything runs under local system. The python script has the path and user credentials set.

Comment: Add the following to your question: What OS? 32 or 64-bit? Include a screenshot of the "Actions" tab of the task.